# Jacob Collier "Hideaway" Analysis

Tags: harmony, jazz, analysis

can Someone please analyse/explain the chordal part of the lyrics
"Even when I close my eyes ,Darling i'll.... "
in the song 'Hideaway' by Jacob Collier's ?? The chords are as folllows:

```
Fmaj7/G  Cmaj9  Dmaj9/A  F#m11/C#   Amaj9  Bbm11  Cmaj7-5
Ev   -   en     when     I         close  my     eyes,
 
C#m11           Eb6add9/G     Bbm7/F     Abmaj9/Eb   Eb9sus
Darling, I will always     stay
 
C6/G   Cmaj7/G   F#dim/G   C#/G
Wide awake           in my
 
G     Gadd4  G  Gmaj7
Hideaway
```

Comment: As you move from one chord to the next, look for (1) common tones, (2) resolutions, and (3) parallel movement (e.g., a set of chord tones that slide up a half step as you move to the next chord). This is how Jacob thinks about his own progressions. He has some great talks on YouTube about how to writes chord progressions.

Answer (score 1):

This is all about voice leading.

For example, consider the first four chords. (Note: I'm not attempting to transcribe Collier's exact voicings; just to illustrate how the chords can be constructed by basic voice-leading principles.)

```
Fmaj7/G  Cmaj9  Dmaj9/A  F#m11/C#

E        D      C#       B
C        B      A        A
                         G#
A        G      F#       F#
F        E      E        E
                D        D

G        C      A        C#
```

One can see how smooth voice-leading can occur, even leaving options to omit notes from certain chords to preserve the total number of voices.

Keep in mind that Collier is not trying to follow standard rules of key relationships, chord relationships, or resolution of dissonances, so an analysis in terms of Roman numeral chords and secondary dominants and such is likely either to be unhelpful or unduly convoluted.

But keep in mind also that chord names as given as descriptive rather than analytical. For example, `Fmaj7/G  Cmaj9` is functionally ambiguous, but `V13  I9`, accurately describes the sound of my above voice-leading example (though not Collier's).

---

For the record, I don't think the transcription is correct to begin with. For example, the very first chord, to my ear, sounds more like Em7/F.